# Family of functions uniformly continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $F$ be a set of functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Below, a naïve definition of: *the functions in* $F$ *are uniformly continuous*

> $∀c\in\mathbb{R}\ \ ∀\varepsilon{>}0\ \ \exists\delta\ \ ∀f{∈} F\ \ ∀ x\ \ \big[\ |x-c|<\delta\to|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon|\ \big]$

How would this definition generalize if $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by a generic topological space?

Comment: Uniform continuity requires a  metric or a uniformity. You cannot do it in a general topological space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general topological space doesn't have enough structure to define a notion of uniform continuity. For that we require something that can measure relative distance, like a metric space.

The definition for uniform continuity of functions $f \colon X \to Y$ in a set $F$ from a metric space $(X,d)$ to a metric space $(Y,d')$ is

$$\forall \, c \in X,\; \forall \, \varepsilon > 0, \; \forall \, f \in F, \; \exists \, \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } \; \forall \, x \in X \quad d(c,x) < \delta \to d'(f(c), f(x)) < \varepsilon$$

Regular continuity on a general topological space can be defined though, using neighbourhoods:

The functions $f\colon X\to Y$ in a set $F$ of functions from a topological space $(X,\tau)$ to a topological space $(Y,\tau')$ are continuous if for any $f \in F$, for any $x \in X$, for any $\tau'$-neighbourhood $N$ of $f(x)$ (*i.e.* a subset of $Y$ containing a $\tau'$-open subset containing $f(x)$), the preimage of $N$ under $f$ is a $\tau$-neighbourhood of $x$.